# First order linear PDE with boundry conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the following PDE:

$$u_x-2xyu_y=0$$

By separation of variables we get: $$ln(y)=x^2-C$$ or $$u(x,y)=f(x^2-ln(y))$$

Now i'm supposed to solve the equation with the boundry condition : $u(1,y)=y^2$ and answer the question:"For which part of the x-y plane
does this boundary condition fix the solution?" And then i'm stuck. With that boundry condition we get $u(1,y)=f(1-ln(y))$ and I don't know how to solve that. Maybe i made a mistake somewhere? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_x-2xyu_y=0$$
You made amistake in your calculus. It isn't possible to say whère is the mistake without knowing all the steps of your calculus.

The general solution solution of the PDE isn't $\quad u(x,y)=F\big(x^2-\ln|y|\big)\quad$ but is :
$$u(x,y)=f\big(x^2+\ln|y|\big)$$

I suppose that your main difficulty is to determine the particular solution of the PDE which satisfies the condition $u(1,y)=y^2$. A straightforward method is :

$$u(1,y)=y^2=f\big(1+\ln|y|\big)$$

Let $X=1+\ln|y|\quad\implies\quad y=e^{X-1}$

$$y^2=f(X)=e^{2(X-1)}$$
Now the function $f(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x^2+\ln|y|$
$$u(x,y)=e^{2(x^2+\ln|y|-1)}$$
$$u(x,y)=e^{-2}y^2e^{2x^2}$$